# Checking whether sets of points are correlated

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I have a set of points for three variables that I'm trying to correlate. I have used Matlab's "corrplot" command to get the correlation matrix, Pearson's correlation coefficient and the p-value. The results are as show below:

[image]

With:

R =

```
1.0000   -0.6496    0.8566
```

-0.6496    1.0000   -0.6613

```
0.8566   -0.6613    1.0000
```

PValue =

```
1.0000    0.0163    0.0002
0.0163    1.0000    0.0138
0.0002    0.0138    1.0000
```

The obtained values look promising but I want to make sure that I have used the right correlation tool. Is Pearson's suitable for my data as presented? Are the results accurate in the sense that I can see moderate to strong correlation between variables?

I would appreciate your feedback.

Regards

Comment: "Suitable" depends on what you want to learn about your data.  There's nothing inherently problematic with using any kind of correlation coefficient you would like.  Could you elaborate on what kind(s) of conclusion(s) you're hoping to draw from this analysis?

Comment: Thank you for replying. What I was worried about is whether I can use the Pearson's for my case? I think that my data is normally distributed but I'm not sure. I'm trying to make sure that I'm using a suitable correlation technique for my case since that I want to prove strong correlation between some of the variable.

Comment: The normality of the distribution is not relevant for deciding whether or not to examine Pearson's correlation coefficient.  (I know, I know--you can find this claim that Normality is needed in [a gazillion places on the Web,](https://www.google.com/search?q=normal+pearson+correlation) including here on CV: but it's just not true. Use this to weed out the awful information you find: if a site makes this claim without qualification, *don't read anything more on that site!*)  Normality has some relevance for hypothesis tests about that correlation coefficient, but that's not what you are asking.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. Do you think that I can say that there is a strong correlation between var1 and var3 (r=0.86 and P-value=0.0002) based on the results that I got? My other question is, do you suggest that other correlation coefficients can be used "like Kendall" based on the scatter plots of my data or Pearson's would do for my case? I'm an outsider in the field of statistics and I'm trying to establish a certain relationship for my thesis based on these results?

Comment: You would be better off describing the problem you actually have.  It looks likely that pursuing such an analysis of correlation coefficients might not address your actual scientific problem.

Comment: I'm trying to correlate var3 with var1 and var2. I know beforehand that there is a relationship but I'm trying to quantify it using correlation coefficients. That is why I ave used Pearson's coefficient.